# Under what conditions can a re-married Catholic couple receive the sacrament of the eucharist?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, communion, canon-law

According to [familiaris consortio](http://www.vatican.va/holy_father/john_paul_ii/apost_exhortations/documents/hf_jp-ii_exh_19811122_familiaris-consortio_en.html), the only case where a "*civilly*" re-married Catholic may receive communion, is where they repent and live like brother-sister, so to speak.

Are there other, perhaps special situations, where such a Catholic may be allowed to receive the Eucharist? Is there some applicable canon law, other papal, or something in the catechism that I may not be aware of?

We are assuming that the re-married catholic had a prior valid marriage in Catholic church that has not yet been declared null, and that the second marriage is a civil marriage only.

Comment: Would you consider the case where the person has civilly remarried the same person who they previously civilly divorced to be a valid special case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Are there other, perhaps special situation, where such a Catholic - divorced and remarried - may be allowed to receive the Eucharist?*

**No there aren't**
*Unless a declaration of nullity [cf.[entire Ch 1 (Art 1-7) Code of Canon Law](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P6J.HTM)] is issued on the prior marriage, and the [current marriage convalidated](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P46.HTM).*

> a. *Epikeia and aequitas canonica* exist in the sphere of human and
>   purely ecclesiastical norms of great significance, but cannot be
>   applied to those norms over which the Church has no discretionary
>   authority. The indissoluble nature of marriage is one of these norms
>   which goes back to Christ Himself and is thus identified as a norm of
>   divine law. The Church cannot sanction pastoral practices - for
>   example, sacramental pastoral practices - which contradict the clear
>   instruction of the Lord.
>
> **In other words, if the prior marriage of two divorced and remarried members of the faithful was valid, under no circumstances can their
>   new union be considered lawful and therefore reception of the
>   sacraments is intrinsically impossible. The conscience of the
>   individual is bound to this norm without exception.<sup>[2](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P46.HTM)</sup>**
>
> <sup>[2](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P46.HTM) Cf. Angel Rodríguez Luño, *L’epicheia nella cura pastorale
>   dei fedeli divorziati risposati, ibid.*, pp. 75-87; Piero Giorgio
>   Marcuzzi, S.D.B., *Applicazione di "aequitas et epikeia" ai contenuti
>   della Lettera della Congregazione per la Dottrina della Fede del 14
>   settembre 1994, ibid.*, pp. 88-98; Gilles Pelland, S.J., *La pratica
>   della Chiesa antica relativa ai fedeli divorziati risposati, ibid.*,
>   pp. 99-131.</sup>
>
> *Source:* [Objections to the Church's Teaching on the Reception of Holy Communion by Divorced and Remarried Members of the Faithful *by Joseph Cardinal Ratzinger* | Congregation for the Doctrine for the Faith](http://www.doctrinafidei.va/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_19980101_ratzinger-comm-divorced_en.html).

---

Please see also

> [CCC 1665](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c3a7.htm#1665) The remarriage of persons divorced from a living, lawful
>   spouse contravenes the plan and law of God as taught by Christ. They
>   are not separated from the Church, but they cannot receive Eucharistic
>   communion. They will lead Christian lives especially by educating
>   their children in the faith.

And

[CDF October 22, 2014 response](http://rorate-caeli.blogspot.com/2014/11/four-days-after-synod-closed-cdf.html?m=1) to the Question of a French Priest: *"Can a confessor grant absolution to a penitent who, having been religiously married, has contracted a second union following divorce?"*

---

**Endnote**

1. OP contained - *"civilly"* re-married Catholic - wording. If one is re-married, there must have been a prior marriage that ended in a divorce.
2. A *Sacramental marriage* is a marriage between two baptized persons. A valid marriage between a Catholic and a non-baptized person is NOT a sacramental marriage.
3. If a Catholic marries not observing [the Church's laws on marriage](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_P40.HTM), that marriage is invalid.

---

Please see [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33683/is-a-catholic-annulment-divorce-in-a-catholic-way/33687#33687) to: *Is a Catholic annulment divorce in a Catholic way?*

Comment: It may be worthwhile to update in answer in light of  Amoris Laetitia.

Comment: @Belinda *Amoris Laetitia* did not change Church teaching, the Catechism or Canon Law.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I agree that Amoris Laetitia did not change teaching, however it did mention the issue of culpability, which, while always part of the doctrine I think was made more explicit there. If not I would be happy to say that if the couple are seen a not culpable for the sin they may receive, but those circumstances would be rare.

Comment: You need to address dispensations to be complete, which are covered in canon law.