# Are couples with secular marriages not allowed to serve in their Catholic parish?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, canon-law, lay-ministry

Are couples who are not married in the Catholic Church, but are married civilly, really not allowed to serve in their parish?

What I mean by "serve" is to act as a head of a particular parish organization or even as a lector.

Kindly give me the exact law on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Under what conditions can a re-married Catholic couple receive the sacrament of the eucharist?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33657/under-what-conditions-can-a-re-married-catholic-couple-receive-the-sacrament-of)

Comment: "couples who are not married in the Catholic church" is very vague. Does it mean couples married civilly only? Concubinage? Couples married before conversion to Catholicism? And what do you mean by "serve in their Catholic parish"?

Comment: @Geremia I don't think that serving in lay ministry etc is a duplicate of receiving the eucharist.

Comment: Some context for this would be helpful.  Do you mean couples who are cohabiting, unmarried?  In invalid 2nd marriages in defiance of church teaching?  Or just couples who had a secular wedding before becoming Catholic?  And where did you see this "not allowed"?

Comment: In most European countries  it is required by law to marry secular first before a marriage in church. A contract between the Vatican and the national governments is even granting this. Some couples wait even multiple years between secular and church marriage! Even people having a position in the catholic church like cantors or sacristans and similar people. So at least "not **yet** married in the Church" is not a problem.

Comment: This is a really good question; I searched for about 20 minutes and found surprisingly little. However, it would definitely help for you to clarify what "serve" means in this case. Serving by helping for a fundraiser would be quite different than serving by being an ecclesial lay minister.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. To Thunderforge, what I mean by "serve" is to act as a head of a particular parish organization or even as a lector.

Comment: @MartinRosenau, that's not true at all. You can marry in the church and the civil offices will issue you a marriage certificate. You don't need to go through a civil marriage ceremonial again if you already undertook the religious.  You just need to let the civil offices know you are getting married in the church.

Comment: @Grasper I don't know which European countries are affected. However at least here in Germany you must have married in the civil office before you can marry in the church. You can't marry in the church unless you are **already** secularly married.

Comment: @MartinRosenau, well that is weird and sounds like discrimination. Is there any special power in a civil ceremony? All they need is the signatures. Eastern EU allows weddings in the church and proceeds with the paperwork afterward.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to depend on circumstances. You may have a situation where one or both parties were baptized Catholic before the marriage, but were married outside the Church without permission. And, you may have a situation where the couple was married before either became Catholic.

In the scenario where a couple were married outside the Church despite one or both already having been baptized, [Convalidation](https://www.catholicmarriageprep.com/convalidation) may be in order. This is a rite by which the marriage is made Sacramentally valid within the Church. This, however, would not preclude the couple from participating in parish life. They simply would not be permitted to receive the sacraments until the convalidation was completed.

In the scenario where a couple were both married naturally, prior to either's baptism, there is no reason why they should be barred from the full Catholic life, sacraments included. whichever of them wished to convert would need to attend RCIA and eventually receive the sacraments of initiation. After this, they could fully participate in parish life without issue.

Lastly, you may have the case of divorced and remarried Catholics. Here, I am assuming that the past marriage was never annulled. In this scenario, just as with the first, access to the sacraments would not be permitted. However, except where there is danger of scandal, other participation in parish life may be permitted. Catholics in this situation would need to receive an annulment prior to convalidation. Or, they could separate from their civil spouse, or, if the situation requires it, "live as brother and sister."